# Add input field onclick with new name

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display a new input field with a new name everytime a button is clicked. how do I achieve that? I found solutions to adding the input but none mentions adding a new name to it.

HTML:

```
<a href="" onclick="addKeywordFields()">Add a keyword</a>
<div id="fieldContainer"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function addKeywordFields() {
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("fieldContainer");
    mydiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("<input type='text' name=''>"))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `document.createTextNode` to create an input. This will only create a text element with content specified inside it.

Instead you should create an input using `document.createElement('input')` and specify its type and name.

Since you need a dynamic name, you have to integrate a dynamic name generation logic. Here I used `(new Date()).toISOString()` since this will e unique each time. Instead you have to use your own logic.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
function addKeywordFields() {
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("fieldContainer");
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'text';
    input.name = (new Date()).toISOString(); // Some dynamic name logic
    mydiv.appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<a onclick="addKeywordFields()">Add a keyword</a>
<div id="fieldContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a ton of DOM methods designed to create, destroy, move, etc. There's generally three ways to create a DOM element programmatically:

- clone an element with `.cloneNode()` and `.append()`
- parse a string that represents HTML (aka `htmlString`) use `.insertAdjacentHTML()` instead of `.innerHTML`
- create an element with `.createElement()` and `.append()`

Assigning attributes/properties to an element can be done initially with `.setAttribute()` once an attribute has been assigned to an element, it is technically a property. This distinction between attribute and property is blurry because methods seem to work 100% as does assigning properties. jQuery is not so flexible in this instance, `.attr()` and `.prop()` have silently failed on me when I forget about attribute/property quirks.

I rarely use methods to assign attributes, properties are terse and simple to use, here's a few common ones:

```
obj.id = "ID", obj.className = "CLASS", obj.name = "NAME"❉, 
obj.type = "TEXT", obj.dataset.* = "*"
```

<sup>❉This is the property you use to set/get `name` attribute</sup>

- I always add a `<form>` if there's multiple form controls. There are special features and terse syntax if you use interfaces like **HTMLFormElement**<sup>✤</sup> and **HTMLFormControlsCollection**<sup>✼</sup>. Moreover having a `<form>` you can use it to listen for events for everything within it<sup>❉</sup> and also take advantage of special form events like "input", "change", "submit", etc.
- `HTMLFormElement.elements` collects all form controls (listed below)
  `<button>`, `<fieldset>`, `<input>`, `<object>`, `<output>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`.
  From the `.elements` property, any form control can be referenced by `#id` or `[name]`. If there is a group of form controls that share a `[name]` they can be collected into a HTMLCollection.

**References**

[HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement)<sup>✤</sup>

[HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)<sup>✼</sup>

[Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

[Event Delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)<sup>❉</sup>

***Further details are commented in example below***

```js
// Reference the form (see HTMLFormElement)
const UI = document.forms.UI;
// Register form to click event
UI.addEventListener('click', makeInput);
// Define a counter outside of function
let dataID = 0;
// Pass Event Object
function makeInput(e) {
  /* 
  "this" is the form
  .elements property is a collection of all form controls 
  (see HTMLFormsCollection)
  */
  const io = this.elements;
  // Event.target points to the tag user clicked
  const clk = e.target;
  /* 
  This is the fieldset containing the inputs it's in bracket notation 
  instead of dot notation because it's a hyphenated property
  */
  const grp = io['form-group'];
  // This is the static input
  const inp = io.data;

  // if the clicked tag is a button...
  if (clk.matches('button')) {
    // ...increment the counter
    dataID++;
    /*
    This switch() delegates what to do by the clicked button's [name].
    Each case is a different way to create an element and assign a unique 
    [name] by concatenating the "data" with the current number of dataID
    */
    switch (clk.name) {
      case 'clone':
        const copy = inp.cloneNode(true);
        copy.name = 'data' + dataID;
        grp.append(copy);
        break;
      case 'html':
        const htmlStr = `
        <input name="data${dataID}">`;
        grp.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', htmlStr);
        break;
      case 'create':
        const tag = document.createElement('input');
        tag.name = 'data' + dataID;
        grp.append(tag);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
};
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
}

fieldset {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-startd;
  max-width: 90%;
}

input,
button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

input {
  width: 150px;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form id='UI'>
  <fieldset name='btn-group'>
    <button name='clone' type='button'>Clone Node</button>
    <button name='html' type='button'>Parse htnlString</button>
    <button name='create' type='button'>Create Element</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name='form-group'>
    <input name='data'>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```